# if block fails to create temp table in a procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl, tempdb, temporary-tables

I'm attempting to do this in a procedure:

```
DECLARE @a bit = 1;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #aTemp FROM OPENROWSET( ... );

    IF @a = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT ... INTO #bTemp FROM #aTemp;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT ... INTO #bTemp FROM #aTemp;
    END
END
```

I get the error:

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
There is already an object named '#bTemp' in the database.
```

Why is this happening and is there a work around?

**Update**

I've attempted to add a `DROP` statement as suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/45535754-514f-4ce5-baee-d43eb543f931/select-into-temp-table), but it still does not work:

```
DECLARE @a bit = 1;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #aTemp FROM OPENROWSET( ... );

    IF @a = 0
    BEGIN
        IF OBJECT_ID('[tempdb]..#bTemp') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE #bTemp;
        END

        SELECT ... INTO #bTemp FROM #aTemp;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF OBJECT_ID('[tempdb]..#bTemp') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE #bTemp;
        END

        SELECT ... INTO #bTemp FROM #aTemp;
    END
END
```

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do the workaround might be to use Table Variables.

Comment: Can you describe what is different when `@a` is 0 and when it isn't 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx#languageReferenceRemarksToggle):

> If more than one temporary table is created inside a single stored procedure or batch, they must have different names.

I ended up creating the table before the `IF` block like so:

```
DECLARE @a bit = 1;
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('[tempdb]..#bTemp') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #bTemp;
    END

    CREATE TABLE #bTemp (
        [c] int);

    IF @a = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #bTemp
        SELECT 1 AS [c];
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #bTemp
        SELECT 1 AS [c];
    END

    DROP TABLE #bTemp;
END
```

Comment: Inside a procedure you don't need to drop the temp table. In fact, you should not, as there can be a significant performance penalty for it. Just create the temp table at the beginning of the procedure and use it throughout. It will automatically go out of scope at the end of the procedure. You also don't need to do the `IF EXISTS...DROP` at the beginning as any existing temp table with the same name that was created outside of the procedure will be eclipsed inside. (See http://sqlity.net/en/1109/temp-tables-scoping-eclipsing/ for details.)

Comment: @SebastianMeine Did not know. Very useful information. Will definitely practice this going forward. Does going out of scope also apply for `##` tables?

Comment: Don't use `##` tables. The scoping is a bit different but, more importantly, they effectively change concurrency to exactly one user.

Comment: @SebastianMeine - Can you elaborate on the "significant performance penalty"? AFAIK if the `#temp` table is able to be cached it will still be cached anyway even if a `DROP` statement is encountered.

Comment: @MartinSmith, the exact rules around this are a little wage and I have not done extensive testing on it. You are certainly running the lowest risk by creating the table once and not in any way altering or dropping it afterwards. That also gives you the added benefit of less clutter in your code.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, how are ##tables forcing single threading? I can see that if created inside a long transaction, but not in general. - Independent of that I agree that you should not use them.

Comment: @SebastienMeine the ##table does not go out of scope until the session that created it goes out of scope (it outlives the procedure and the transaction). So it another user calls this procedure while the first one is still connected, they're either going to share the ##table or they'll get an error.

Comment: @SebastianMeine I posted an answer to elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

This is NOT an answer to the question, only a demonstration to @SebastienMeine how ##global temp tables can kill concurrency.

In one window, do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.floob1
  @p INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT a = @p INTO ##floob;
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.floob2
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT a FROM ##floob;
END
GO

EXEC dbo.floob1 @p = 1;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00';
EXEC dbo.floob2;
```

Result:

```
a
----
1
```

Then open another window, and do this:

```
BEGIN TRY
  EXEC dbo.floob1 @p = 2;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT 'Something bad happened.';
END CATCH
GO
EXEC dbo.floob1 @p = 2;
GO
EXEC dbo.floob2;
```

Results:

> Something bad happened.
>   
> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Procedure floob1
>   
> There is already an object named '##floob' in the database.

```
a
----
1
```

So the ##table still exists even though the procedure it was created in has long since finished.

Then after the first window has finished, try running this portion in the first window again:

```
EXEC dbo.floob1 @p = 1;
```

Result:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Procedure floob1
>   
> There is already an object named '##floob' in the database.

So the ##table still exists even though the same user is simply trying to create again.

This illustrates that:

1. only one user can effectively call this procedure at a time
2. the standard advice to not bother dropping #temp tables (which I am on the fence about) does not apply in the same way to ##temp tables.

Comment: If I read this correctly, I should continue to check and drop any `##` tables used in my procedure?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO yes, unless you can guarantee that no two users will ever call this stored procedure at the same time, or that the same user might not retry on the same connection (or while their original connection is still active), you should treat `##global` tables like permanent tables - since, while they exist, that's essentially what they are. Or - better yet - simply don't use `##global` temp tables.

Comment: Thanks, @AaronBertrand. When I think about concurrency I think about locking and blocking so this did not come to mind, but you have a very valid point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which I use if temp table can't be created upfront and don't want to put core logic in dynamic SQL.

```
IF 1 = 1 -- Replace with actual condition
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #tmp1 FROM dbo.Table1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #tmp2 FROM dbo.Table2
END

-- Inserting data into global temp table so sql server can't complain on not recognizing in a context
DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(MAX)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @Command = 'SELECT * INTO ##tmp FROM #tmp1'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Command = 'SELECT * INTO ##tmp FROM #tmp2'
END

EXECUTE(@Command)
SELECT * INTO #tmpFinal FROM ##tmp -- Again passing data back to local temp table from global temp table to avoid seeing red mark

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##tmp
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp1
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp2

SELECT * FROM #tmpFinal

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpFinal') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpFinal
```

Comment: Note that the [currently accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49629/116653) accomplishes the same thing without a global temp table, and without dynamic SQL. That said, I don't see anything in the example that would prevent the creation of the temp table before the `IF` statement. About the only thing I can think of that would prevent this is if the tables would not follow the same structure; however, then you wouldn't be able to use the resulting table with a single SQL statement (or you *could* make the temp table's structure the same).